# AWS ELB OutOfService with instance having 2 ethernet interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an instance having 2 ethernet interfaces. My primary IP is configured on eth1 & the ssh service listens on the eth1 interface IP. My Web Application listens on the secondary IP.

After configuring the AWS ELB for the instance I get the OutOfService error.
Looks like the ELB service is trying to reach for the http instance on the primary IP which is not available. Is there a way I can get ELB to run the health check on secondary IP instead of the primary IP.

Note: I currently won't be able to switch over the webapplication to listen on primary IP.

Comment: IIRC, the ELB will always check the primary IP. I don't have any suggestions other than to have the web application listen on the primary IP. Is there a reason to have two ethernet interfaces?

Comment: We use the primary IP for console management & Secondary IP for web management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toiling around with different solutions, I managed to get this working by forwarding the port 80 request on eth1 to eth2. This helped ELB in establishing the http connection.